# SQL Server files configuration

Tags: sql-server, database, transactions, sql-server-2016, logfile

I have a database that receives information per second from multiple devices via SNMP, GPS and others. The insertion rate of each device is 1sec and we speak of a group of devices ranging between 80 and 120.

This is generating a significant growth of the database, to the point that it is growing at a rate increasingly close to 1 gb daily.

What is the growth configuration and minimum sizes of the data server (SQL Server 2016) should have in its logs and data files so the db is as fluid as possible?

Any additional recommendations regarding capabilities, maintenance and best practices in relation to the scenario described above?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

You should never have auto-growth events. Ideally, you would want to grow your data files to a size large enough so that you will not be troubled by auto-growth events, ever.

See [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23305/sql-server-best-practices-for-growing-database-files) over at DBA Stack Exchange that relates to growing log files.